# IcCube Connection with SSAS; OLAP Dtatabase

Tags: iccube

I want to create a cube Data Source based on an existing OLAP Database in SQL server analysis services.

I tried to access the Database throw a http access, but I couldn't do it. So I tried to add jdbc4olapndriver as plugin to connect with DATABASE, with same researches I found that we can use it like follows: (`jdbc: jdbc4olap: http: //server: port/OLAP/msmdpump.dll`). 
But I haven't an idea about the process of adding plugin in icCube.
Any help or suggestion please?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Accessing SQL server tables is performed through a JDBC driver ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/ds_database.php)). So create a new SQL data source and select the "SQL Server" driver. Then enter amongst other the address of the SQL server and leave blank the port number (default:1433).

Note: the URL you're talking about (msmdpump.dll) has nothing to do with tables in SQL server but this is related to accessing OLAP cubes for example from Excel.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to Access SSAS Database wich contain OLAP cubes with iceCube, not accessing an SQL Server tables

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: there is no way to add MSOLAP provider as plugin in icCube? in this case we can connect with DB, because the problem is only that we haven't a provider for OLAP DB.